# javascript form validation which excludes hidden dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

The code for my project is http://jsfiddle.net/CVS2F/2/. I also have a submit button which submits the data to mysql, but when i click attending: 'no' there is no value submitted by user as they are not attending dropdowns are hidden but with the code an error pops up anway. is there a way around this to ignore hidden dropdowns?

Comment: which code popups the error, the code in jaavscript or code in php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you ignore hidden page elements when validating using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151375/how-do-you-ignore-hidden-page-elements-when-validating-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In the php code add these lines:

```
if($_REQUEST['yesNo'] == 'yes)
    {
    // form process with list
    }
    else
    {
    // form process without list
    }
```

Comment: sorry not sure if you know what i mean. It is the javascript that is the issue. Even though the dropdowns are hidden when no is selected a validation error still occurs because the drop down = 0. I just need to ignore the hidden drop downs if no is selected