# How do you ignore hidden page elements when validating using javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, drop-down-menu

basically I have attending yes or no.
if 'no' is selected then the drop down menus are hidden.

but when clicked submit a validation error still occurs. Is there a way to ignore hidden elements when validating ?

my page script

```
    1.    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"'>
2.    <!--
3.   function validateForm(){
4.   if(document.colour.list1.selectedIndex==0)
5.   {
6.   alert("Please select an Item.");
7.   document.colour.list1.focus();
8.   return false;
9.   }
10.   return true;
11.   }
12.   //-->
13.  
14. 
15.</script>
16.<script type="text/javascript">
17.window.onload=registerEventHandlers;
18. function registerEventHandlers()             
19.{
20.        document.getElementById("radio1").onclick = function(){
21.                hideDiv(this,"list1")             
22.         };             
23.         document.getElementById("radio2").onclick = function(){
24.                showDiv(this,"list1")                    
25.         };                           
26. }              
27. 
28. function showDiv(targetElement,toggleElementId){                    
29. 
30.         var showAll=document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
31.             i,
32.             re = new RegExp('\\b' + toggleElementId + '\\b');
33.         for(i=0; i < showAll.length; i++){
34.           if (re.test(showAll[i].className)) {
35.               showAll[i].style.visibility="visible";
36.               showAll[i].style.display="block";
37.           }
38.        }                         
39.}            
40.function hideDiv(targetElement,toggleElementId){                
41.        var hideAll=document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
42.            i,
43.            re = new RegExp('\\b' + toggleElementId + '\\b');
44.        for(i=0; i < hideAll.length; i++){
45.            if (re.test(hideAll[i].className)) {
46.               hideAll[i].style.visibility="hidden";
47.               hideAll[i].style.display="none";
48.            }
49.        }                            
50.} 
51.</script>
52. 
53. 
54. 
55.Yes:<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="yesNo" value="yes" />
56.No:<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="yesNo" value="no"/>
57.<div class="list1" style="display: none;" >
58.        <select name="colour">
59.          <option>Please Select</option>
60.          <option>red</option>
61.            <option>orange</option>
62.            <option>blue</option>
63.        </select>
64.</div>
65.  <div class="list1" style="display: none;" >
66.<select name="shade">
67.  <option>Please Select</option>
68.  <option>dark</option>
69.    <option>light</option>
70.</select>
71.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change your javascript code to check whether those items are hidden and skip the validation code if they are hidden.  You'd have to show us how they were hidden and what your HTML is for us to offer the simplest way to detect if they are hidden.

P.S. You should know that hidden items will still be sent with a form submission so you may need to make sure your server knows which data is expected to be valid and which is not (because it was hidden).

Comment: You should look into using jQuery for this it'd make this a whole lot easier than straight javascript.

Comment: @thenetimp - you should direct that comment to user1188711 as a comment on their question, not as a comment on my answer.

Comment: I guess the way I use stack overflow is if I am adding onto a comment or solution I add the comment to an answer that is correct instead of flooding new answers. so I was trying to direct it at him, just didn't feel it needed a new answer, since your answer was correct.

Comment: @thenetimp - I didn't propose a new answer.  I proposed you leave a comment on the OP's question instead of a comment on my answer.  That directs the comment to the OP, not to me which appears to have been your goal.

Comment: I have edit my post and added html and java. I am happy enough to use javascript for now. so you help would be appreciated on how to ignore hidden dropdown on validation

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Sorry just getting use to being able to comment.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you the option of using jQuery, I would suggest you do. Then it's as simple as doing

```
if($(element).is(":visible")){

}
```

Of course you need to replace "element" with the element you're testing for validation.